# Facebook Login generic error - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

I have developed a Website on a dev environment, using Laravel and Socialite. 
Months ago, I set up a project on Facebook Login in order to use it on my website. Login works fine on this environment, no errors.

Now I deployed it to a production environment, and set up a new FB Login for it. But now I got a generic error in the first login attempt.Image below.

Messages are in portuguese. In english: "An error occurred. Close and open your browser again".

[image]

If I try again, I get no errors, and Login works. 
I have tried with 3-4 test users provided by Facebook, and with all of them the same occur: that error on first attempt, but works fine on a second attempt.

Use the same process on dev (create test user, try to login) and everything works fine. Login with no errors on first attempt.

The first project, for dev, was using API version 2.1. Update to 3.3 and everything continued to works fine.

The second project, for production, already started with API 3.3, and got all the errors described above.

As I copied all files dev->prod, every version (Laravel, Socialite... ) are the same on both environment. Just update hosts, users , database name (...)

Have now idea how to troubleshoot it.
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: I found the problem. Nothing related to Socialite, or related to Facebook, although the error above. Even close and open again would not work. Just an one-letter typo on config when deploying to prod. env. !